# Strange C++ error on Xcode and rocksdb

Tags: xcode, rocksdb

I am trying to use RocksDB on MacOS, with Xcode. I met a strange problem like below

[image: ; is missing, but actually it is there]

Xcode reported that `;` is missing, but it is there. The code comes from [rocksdb](http://rocksdb.org/) without any modification, so it is strange that there is an error.

**Update**

I enabled C++ 11 as following:

[image: enabling C++11]

Comment: Do you have C++11 enabled ?

Comment: Yeah, I enabled C++ 11. I updated the question.

Comment: You just changed the warnings - you need to change the dialect

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right. Thanks a lot,